# can't remove nginx

Tags: apt, apache2, mysql, nginx, purge

I have recently upgraded my virtual machine from Ubuntu 15.04 to Ubuntu 15.10. Previously I was running an Apache2 web server with PHP and MySQL installed. Now when I access localhost, or the IP address (192.168.42.131) I get the following message.

> Welcome to nginx!
>
> If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.
>
> For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
>   Commercial support is available at nginx.com.
>
> Thank you for using nginx.

So after research I ran the following command.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nginx*
```

Originally a few packages were remove resulting in my UI looking weird. When I went to check if I could access my Apache2 web server Nginx welcome message showed again.

Now when I run `sudo apt-get remove --purge nginx*` is results in the following:

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Does anyone know how I can manually remove it from my virtual machine as I need the MySQL database structures.

P.S. access the MySQL server through the commandline is not working either.

Comment: Check and see what's in /var/www/html. I could be that nginx saved it's useless html page there, and apache2 is loading it. I don't know much about nginx, but I know apache2 will load anything found in that folder. If you didn't configure apache2 at all, you could purge it, wipe /var/www/html, and then reinstall apache2... but that's a last case 'idk what I'm doing' approach.

Comment: only `localhost` is loading. `localhost/index.php`, `localhost/phpmyadmin` and `localhost/fdsfdsf` (which should 404, wordpress is installed, htaccess enabled) result in 'Unable to connect'

Comment: Have you resolved this case? I'm in the same trap...

Comment: Yes, kind of. New virtual machine and avoid anything to do with nginx